# Ora -01031 insufficient privileges in Sql Developer Connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In oracle 11g Enterprise edition, I am able to connect to sys as sysdba via terminal.
( docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgZzdjVzgySUFuYUk/edit )

But when I try to connect sys as sysdba via Sql Developer,
the test returns "insufficient privileges" !!
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgZVdvRi1ocUpqVXM/edit

I tried searching for the same. Some of the solutions suggested to edit the file sqlnet.ora.
But I don't have such a file.
What shall I do ?

So I altered the Sys to login without sysdba requirement !
But when I am trying to connection to dmuser on Data Miner, I am not able to connect to Sys when the login prompt for create repository appears.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgUURJYmhSODc0Z3c/edit (This Dialog Box keeps recurring and I am not able to proceed forward)

So I am stuck with the SYS and Data Miner connection.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of your `REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE` database parameter? Normally it should be `EXCLUSIVE`.

Another issue may be if your password file has been created with `nosysdba=Y` option which would prevent connecting remotely as sysdba.

Comment: thank you for your response. I am not sure, I think my installation of 11g itself was flawed. Later I faced few other problems as well. So I switched to 12c, more errors in installation, but successfully resolved and completed. I will have to make initial configuration before proceeding to data miner now.. thank you.

Comment: this knowledge would be handy anyway in my present setup.